# Sublime Text 2 - SublimeREPL - key bindings for eval file stopped working

Tags: python, macos

On mac osx 10.8.4. Sublime Text 2.0.2

My python interpreter invoked through Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python Run current file will run the file that I wish it to run without issue. However, when I invoke Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL -> File (^,,f), nothing happens. Similarly, if I invoke Ctrl+, f nothing happens. I have uninstalled SublimeREPL and then reinstalled, however, I am still seeing the same issue. The user keymap config (Default (OSX).sublime-keymap) is empty.

When I invoke ^,,f the sublime console issues:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 356, in run_
   File "./text_transfer.py", line 124, in run
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Excluding the option of uninstalling and re-install Sublime Text 2, are there any ideas where I might start?

Thanks

**UPDATED**

Uninstalled ST 2, removed contents from ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/

Installed ST 3, package manager, installed SublimeREPL. Create hello.py and add:

```
import sys

def main():
    print "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Invoke Ctrl+, f results in nothing. Replace file contents with:

```
import sys

print "hello"
```

Invoke Ctrl+, f results in hello being echoed to REPL window. Why does the former script not work while the latter runs fine...?

**Resolved**
When opening REPL, I was selecting SublimeREPL -> Python: IPython. Just selecting SublimeREPL -> Python to open the interpreter resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved** When opening REPL, I was selecting SublimeREPL -> Python: IPython. Just selecting SublimeREPL -> Python to open the interpreter resolves the issue.